# Rank of Matrix , Intersection of 3 planes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, plane-geometry

Suppose 3 planes intersect, 2 of the planes are parallel and the system is inconsistent [Just like (b) in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3vYK.png) what would the rank of the matrix be?

$A = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}$

suppose the first and second equation for the plane are parrallel then

$A = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\ka_{11}&ka_{12}&ka_{13}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}$ where $k \in \Bbb{R}$
then we can apply elementary row operations to get

$A = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\0&0&0\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}$ and since the whole system is inconsistent then
$A = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$ and so the rank is 1. Is this a correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic up to here is fine.
$A = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\0&0&0\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}$

I am not sure on your reasoning to eliminate the 3rd row, though.

At this point you have two independent row vectors (because the two planes intersect) and one  $\bf 0$ vector row.

That means you have a rank of $2$